# Mongoose use a variable as model with function find():

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Is it possible to use a variable instead of the name of the model with the function find() in mongoose? For example, if my site can show photo and video based on the last path of the url, that can be either `/photo` or `/video`, can I use the same function to query the database by using a variable as the name of the model like this?

```
const getContent = async (req, res) => {
    const model = req.url;
    const data = await model.find();
}
```

This could save a lot of time and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first create a map out of your available Models, like

```js
const Models = {
  photo : Photo,
  video : Video
};
```

And then use it in your controller like

```js
const getContent = async (req, res) => {
    const model = Models[req.url];
    const data = await model.find();
    res.json(data);
}
```

Be aware, even if it looks like less code needed, there still needs to be appropiate error handling involved.

Comment: I tried this method in many differents ways but never worked, I think that mohammad has the rigth solution.

Comment: @matteo I am 100 % confident that this is a working solution, you probably just copy pasted the whole thing. It depends on how the rest of you file looks. It's alright, Mohammad s solution is another correct and valid one !

Comment: Ah, my bad, you're right, it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, It's not possible, because type of `model` should be `function` not a `string`
you can using if and else for implementation of your business logic like this:

```
const getContent = async (req, res) => {
  let data;
  if (req.url === "photo") {
    data = await photo.find();
  } else if (req.url === "video") {
    data = await video.find();
  }
};
```